# What does this symbol with white rectangles around my vias mean in Altium?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, via

I'm doing a PCB in Altium and I don't know what these white rectangles beside my vias are meant to indicate. A screen shot is below:

[image: Vias with the white symgol that I don't understand]

Comment: Looks like some drc violation, try right clicking it and look for "violation"

Comment: What version of Altium are you using? Haven't seen those symbols before. My guess is that they are symbols to show that the two vias aren't connected..

Answer (score 3):

Since those are vias, what if those symbols were section views of the PCB showing 2 vias which go from the top/bottom to inner layer and stop there? I would guess it means those vias are not through hole; by any chance is it the case?

Comment: I think you're right. The vias go from the bottom layer to an internal layer (blind vias). I tried creating a new via and it started showing the same thing as soon as I changed it from going from the top layer to the bottom layer to going from the top layer to one of the internal layers.

Thanks a  lot!

Answer (score 0):

I use Eagle, not Altium, so this is an educated shot-in-the-dark. Are those possibly really tiny labels/values/names being rendered as solids because of the zoom?

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the via, then view all the associated properties.  There may be an insignificant parameter that has its Visible option button checked.